# How to use YAWS in Erlide - Erlang

Tags: php, erlang, yaws, erlide

I have read that Erlang has a built-in webserver (YAWS); I am developing Erlang using the Eclipse plugin Erlide, I was wondering how I could access such a webserver, for example for running a simply 'hello world' PHP script; just for starting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yaws isn't built into Erlang — the built-in web server in Erlang is called [inets](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_server.html). You can find more information on Yaws at the [Yaws website](http://yaws.hyber.org/), and you can find all the details of its PHP support in its [PDF documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/yaws.pdf). If you run into any trouble getting started with Yaws, you can ask for help on the [Yaws mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/erlyaws-list).

Comment: OK. I don't know why but here it was written so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907144/web-server-for-running-phperlang
Anyway, is inets as powerful as, let's say, Apache or YAWS? I just need to be able to integrate Erlang and PHP.